# Unordered List with checkmarks list-style-positions-outside Text aligned on the left vertically

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to have an unordered list with check-marks and have my text line up in the left and not have my second line of text float to the left and go under the check-marks.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: preco-do elements are considered as in the same line of your `li` 's text, so there is no way to achieve so using preco-do element, is it okay to add a `span` for your checkmark in front of each `li`

Comment: One solution (albeit not the best) would be to add a negative margin (e.g. `margin-left: -1.2em;`) to your pseudo element's selector.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The below code helps you in understanding. [Here's a JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AeY2x/1/).

```
li:before
{
    content: '✔';   
    margin-left: -1em;
    margin-right: .100em;
}

ul
{
   padding-left: 20px;
   text-indent: 2px;
   list-style: none;
   list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Refer this link to get the tick mark: http://amp-what.com/#q=check%20mark

Paste the code in the content property of `li` to get the check mark. 
I hope this will help you. Please vote.

Comment: OK Gourav, your code worked PERFECT :) thank you for laying it out with the checkmark and the link to that awesome amp-what.com site.
--
Also thanks to jasonlyvia and sbat
---
Wish they made it more obvious on how to vote??? I cant find any buttons of options anywhere to vote? Why? I must not have enough rank!!!

Comment: @TonyStates :The up and down arrows beside the Answer.

Comment: @TonyStates Hmmm ok see what you do :)

Comment: I prefer to use the Entity Conversion Calculator rather than the actual check for :before content.
https://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html

Comment: Hi Gourav, I was hoping you can explain the measurements you used. I think I understand the `margin-left:-1em` but how do you get the `margin-right:.100em` and the `text-indent:2px` on the `ul` element?

Comment: This does not work with list items that are multi-line, does it? The lines after the first don't align but rather come below the checkmark.